# perform a operation when checkbox checked nd unchecked in mvc3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have a registration form which has some fields.. say i have 4 textboxes t1,t2,t3,t4

While filling the registration for, when the user fills t1 and t2 and if he checks the checkbox then the data in t1 and t2 should be submitted in t3 and t4 respectively..

when i tried to find  about how to use checkbox in mvc3, i found html helper checkbox and normal html checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x" value="c1">Test<br>
```

how can i use html helper checkbox in my case and autosubmit the fields when the use checks the chekcbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are totally same, 
In Html helper

```
@Html.CheckBox("YourModelProperty", new {id="yourCheckBox"})
```

Or

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.YourProperty, new {id="yourCheckBox"})
```

Now Give your action in the checkBox click function
Like

```
$("#yourCheckBox").click(function(){
//what you want to do!!!
});
```